# hadoop webhdfs ajax request url error

Tags: hadoop, webhdfs

After installation of hadoop 2.6.0, I tested mapreduce and jobs list, everything seems ok, and i can create folder and upload files into dfs.

there is only one problem that where i opened the 50070 port and try to see the detailed file list there comes the error 'Path does not exist on HDFS or WebHDFS is disabled. Please check your path or enable WebHDFS'

and I enabled WebHDFS the error was still there.
i checked the ajax request and found the following url
http://192.168.0.111:50070/webhdfs/v1/undefined?op=LISTSTATUS

why undefined? i changed the undefined to folder name, the server returns the file list in ajax, but why? can anyone help me out! thanks a lot.

Comment: http://192.168.0.111:50070/webhdfs/v1/result2?op=LISTSTATUS
returns following text
{"FileStatuses":{"FileStatus":[
{"accessTime":1491891797305,"blockSize":134217728,"childrenNum":0,"fileId":16418,"group":"supergroup","length":0,"modificationTime":1491891797311,"owner":"root","pathSuffix":"_SUCCESS","permission":"644","replication":2,"storagePolicy":0,"type":"FILE"},
...
]}}

Comment: I finaly find out that  the hadoop monitor works perfect in IE, but can not work in chrome.